# Use sprite into at-breakpoint not run correctly

Tags: breakpoints, susy-compass

When i use sprite into the at-breakpoint($desktop) (susy)  the  generit sprite background image not affect my .logo class

```
SCSS :

@include at-breakpoint($desktop) {
  .logo{
     @include logos-sprite('my-set-m');
  }
}

CSS :

.logos-sprite { background: url('../images/spr/logos.png') no-repeat; }
```

But without at-breakpoint()  it's ok (.logo merged with .logo-sprite) !  (i need include sprite into brakpoint )

```
SCSS :

//@include at-breakpoint($desktop) {
  .logo{
     @include logos-sprite('my-set-m');
  }
//}

CSS :

.logos-sprite, .logo { background: url('../images/spr/logos.png') no-repeat; }
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because magic sprites use `@extend` which is not supported inside media-queries. You will have to use the more finely-tuned compass sprite tools to create your own workaround.

Comment: but if i need to use susy for mediaqueries ?